# Analytic solution for $\min_w \max \{ c_1\|A_1w-b_1\|_2^2, c_2\|A_2w-b_2\|_2^2\}$

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, least-squares

Describe the solution of $$\min_w \max \{ c_1\|A_1w-b_1\|_2^2, c_2\|A_2w-b_2\|_2^2\}$$ for some positive constants $c_1, c_2$.

Is there a keyword I can search or a reference I can look into for this problem? Below has been my attempt so far:

The optimization problem is convex and the solution is either the min of either equation or within their intersection i.e. when $c_1\|A_1w-b_1\|_2^2= c_2\|A_2w-b_2\|_2^2$. That condition turns out to be $w^T(c_1A_1^TA_1-c_2A_2^TA_2)w+ 2[c_2b_2^TA_2 - c_1b_1^TA_1]w+\|c_1b_1\|_2^2 - \|c_2b_2\|_2^2 = 0$. The problem is not strongly convex, so there might be infinitely many solutions. We can also consider the "regularized" version of the problem so that the problem becomes strongly convex and then there is a unique optimal solution.

I can see that the solution must be either "inside" (I want to say convex hull but not sure if that's correct)  or exactly in the intersection $I=\{w \mid c_1\|A_1w-b_1\|_2^2= c_2\|A_2w-b_2\|_2^2\}$ -- since the objective is convex -- and that when the solution is not on the boundary of that set, it is the min of either quadratic. This intersection set $I$ is not a convex set nor even it is the boundary of its convex hull (when $c_1A_1^TA_1-c_2A_2^TA_2$ is neither PSD nor NSD which seems possible) so that makes things more complicated.

My intuition is that when $c_1A_1^TA_1-c_2A_2^TA_2$ is PSD (or NSD) i.e. the intersection set $I$ is the boundary of its convex hull (is there a name for such a set?), then the problem is a constraint optimization problem with the equality constraint to check for if the solution is in $I$ or not. If not then it is a simple casework to figure which quadratic has the min.

Am I on the right track? Any pointer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may add the size of variables (Is $A_1$ or $A_2$ full rank?) etc.

Comment: They are arbitrary $m_1\times n_1$ and $m_2\times n_2$ matrices. Not necessarily full rank but if assuming the columns or rows are independent helps then it should be fine.

Comment: So your question is to deal with minimizing a convex quadratic function subject to a quadratic function equality-constrained. Did you try Lagrange multiplier?

Comment: I am not sure if Lagrange multiplier would work with a quadratic equality constraint, since that makes the problem no longer convex (since the feasible region might not be convex anymore). But I guess when the constraint quadratic is convex, we can solve the inequality version of it (given that we know which sign makes the constraint convex) since the solution is inside the convex hull of $I$ in that case. In that case, LM might work.

Comment: Actually, I think no analytic solution (non-numerical solution) for general cases.

Comment: Yea I suspect so too :(. This is such a simple problem for a computer to solve, but I am trying to make certain statements that an analytic solution would be nice.